# Why do you use the auxiliary verb in this sentence?

Tags: questions, auxiliary-verbs, do-support, pied-piping

> What kind of music **does** Jane like listening to?

1. Why do you use the auxiliary verb in this sentence?
2. Why is the preposition at the end of the sentence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Because  [***do*-support** for questions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do-support) is as fundamental — and obligatory — an aspect of English grammar as inversion is. *Do*-support is not something that many other European languages make use **of** [`<——`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preposition_stranding) though.

   Although [McWhorter has posited a Celtic origin for it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3ADo-support#Origin_of_do-support.3F), this is a minority view among linguists. Given its existence even in Old English and its concurrent appearance in the Celtic tongues, it seems more likely that *do*-support [“arose in response to a gap in the developing auxiliary system”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Do-support/Origin) rather than from a Celtic innovation somehow imported by English.
2. Because despite its Latinate lexicon spliced in [`<——`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preposition_stranding) after the Norman Conquest and subsequent occupation, grammatically and genetically English remains a fundamentally Germanic language like Danish or Dutch or German **ᴀɴᴅ ɴᴏᴛ** a Romance language like French or Spanish or Portuguese or Italian, [***pied-piping***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pied-piping) is so unnatural for us that doing **without** [`<——`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preposition_stranding) is just something you’ll have to get used **to**. [`<——`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preposition_stranding)

Comment: "like Danish or Dutch or German ᴀɴᴅ  ᴛ a Romance language like French or Spanish " -- What word did you mean to write where the gap is?